# Alfresco Community Edition 6.2 - Login Issue

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I have login issue with **Alfresco Community Edition 6.2** where the logging of users is taking **more than 3minutes** to login to Alfresco. When I tried to **upgrade from Alfresco 5.1 to Alfresco 6.2** in **Windows Server**, this login issue is shown in log file when I try to login. I have attached the error log below.

How to resolve this issue so that the users does not take more time to login.

**Error Log**:

```
2023-07-11 10:11:39,830 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [http-nio-8080-exec-19] Exception calling (GET) http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/people/admin/sites?alf_ticket=TICKET_734abf90ef7e85991ea3b5848219cea73a2e76e6
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)



2023-07-11 10:11:39,836 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [http-nio-8080-exec-19] Error status 408 The stack details have been removed for security reasons.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.RemoteClient.service(RemoteClient.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.RemoteClient.service(RemoteClient.java:934)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.RemoteClient.call(RemoteClient.java:657)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.RemoteClient.call(RemoteClient.java:591)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:70)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.RequestCachingConnector.call(RequestCachingConnector.java:91)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.AuthenticatingConnector.call(AuthenticatingConnector.java:136)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptRemoteConnector.call(ScriptRemoteConnector.java:95)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptRemote.call(ScriptRemote.java:179)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor926.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:138)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:226)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:45)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__G__DMS_BDC_tomcat_webapps_share_WEB_INF_classes_alfresco_site_webscripts_org_alfresco_components_dashlets_my_profile_get_js_8._c_main_2(file:/G:/DMS-BDC/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/dashlets/my-profile.get.js:18)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__G__DMS_BDC_tomcat_webapps_share_WEB_INF_classes_alfresco_site_webscripts_org_alfresco_components_dashlets_my_profile_get_js_8.call(file:/G:/DMS-BDC/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/dashlets/my-profile.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:76)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__G__DMS_BDC_tomcat_webapps_share_WEB_INF_classes_alfresco_site_webscripts_org_alfresco_components_dashlets_my_profile_get_js_8._c_script_0(file:/G:/DMS-BDC/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/dashlets/my-profile.get.js:95)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__G__DMS_BDC_tomcat_webapps_share_WEB_INF_classes_alfresco_site_webscripts_org_alfresco_components_dashlets_my_profile_get_js_8.call(file:/G:/DMS-BDC/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/dashlets/my-profile.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:409)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3566)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__G__DMS_BDC_tomcat_webapps_share_WEB_INF_classes_alfresco_site_webscripts_org_alfresco_components_dashlets_my_profile_get_js_8.call(file:/G:/DMS-BDC/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/dashlets/my-profile.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__G__DMS_BDC_tomcat_webapps_share_WEB_INF_classes_alfresco_site_webscripts_org_alfresco_components_dashlets_my_profile_get_js_8.exec(file:/G:/DMS-BDC/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/dashlets/my-profile.get.js)
```

I have tried **tunning of solr and java memory** to make users fast login but this did not make any changes to the login time.

Hi Sir thank you for sharing the information

This is Sai Kumar S, i am working on Alfresco, i have question that how can we upgrade from alfresco 5.2 to 6.2 with data migration in Windows machine

Like we have around 12TB of contentstore, 7TB of contentstore.deleted, 78gb of postgresql data, 178gb of solr4 in alf_data folder.

How to migrate this data from alfresco 5.2 to 6.2

I have tried a procedure for upgradation from Alfresco 5.2 to 6.2

1. Stopped alfrescoTomcat Service
2. alfrescoPostgreSQL kept running for taking backup, i used this query to backup from postgresql 9.4 --> pg_dump.exe -U alfresco -d alfresco -f filepath/filename.sql

3.After taking back-up of db file.sql it is around 10gb.

4. Stopped both tomcat and postgres services.
5. Took backup of contentstore and contententstore.deleted from 5.2 alf_data folder

6.I have installed Alfresco 6.2 by referring your javaworld-abhinav.blogspot.com

7. I have done this installation in windows server using distribution package (without using docker)

8.For restoring postgresql i have used this query to restore the data from .SQL file --> psql.exe -U alfresco -d alfresco -f filepath/filename.sql so while restoring it shows one duplicate value in alf_node table(so we tried to restore the same with that duplicate) ---> is their any issue for this duplicate while restoring or any other method than I can use it.

9. Restored alf_data folder using contentstore and contentstore.deleted

10.Due to solr upgradation from 4 to 6 the indexing process is very slow and for indexing it is showing 30days to complete the indexing process.

11. Is their any method for faster reindexing for solr6.
12. This procedure which i am following is correct method for Upgradation or not can you suggest me.
13. The system configuration is of 256GB Ram and 30TB of Storage.

Thanks & Regards
Sai Kumar S

Comment: How did you do the upgrade ? Maybe it's the main problem, can you rollback ?
You should always validate your new installation (6.2 in you case) before the upgrade.
Follow documentation for more detail : https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/community/upgrade/#validate-upgrade

Comment: Sir i have edited the post can you please check now that how i have upgraded the Alfresco Community Edititon from 5.2 to 6.2

Comment: Have you tried and validated the installation of Alfresco 6.2 before transferring the data ?